# SplFxiedArray in php

Tags: php

```
<?php

$arrA=SplFixedArray::fromArray([true]);
$arrB=SplFixedArray::fromArray([false]);
var_dump($arrA == $arrB);
```

Why the result is true?

And:

```
<?php

    $arrA=SplFixedArray::fromArray([true]);
    $arrB=SplFixedArray::fromArray([false]);
    var_dump($arrA);
    var_dump($arrA == $arrB);
```

Why the result is false?

My php version is php 5.6.20.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm - looks like there is a *related* [open bug on php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63879)